Order of an element in symmetric group
In $S_3$, order of $(1 2 3)$ is $3$ and order of $(1 3 2)$ is also $3$, $e = (1 2 3) \circ ( 1 3 2)$, order of $e$ is $1$. So we got $\text{odd} \times \text{odd} = \text{odd}$.
How it is possible?

The group $S_3$ is not abelian though... The order of the product can be arbitrary.

Although $(123)$ has odd order it is an even permutation. Is this what is confusing you?

C'mon, orders don't multiply, for one thing. (Though they would if the cycles were disjoint and the lengths/orders were relatively prime.)
$(123)$ and $(132)$ are not disjoint.   If they were,  the order of the product/ composition would be the lcm of their orders.
When you take cycles that aren't disjoint,  different things can happen. For instance,  $(12)(123)=(23)$ has order two.
Or, $(34)(123)=(1243)$ has order four. Or, $(345)(123)=(124531)$ has order six.
